# spring boot server stops after main method execution

Tags: spring-boot

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)
```

(application stops after main class execution.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us some logs and code, just by saying it stops no one can help

Comment: There are no logs printed other than this in the console
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.3.RELEASE)

Comment: It is a simple application with one Class which has the main method running the SpringApplication.run(App.class, args); thats it.

Comment: dependencies you added? also what all steps you did please

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

 </dependencies>
Simply ran the application as javaapllication in eclipse IDE

Comment: Why would you use 1.3.3 release? try using 1.5.6, also show you config class

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/Bolt/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar' in project 'Demo' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file Demo  Build path Build Path Problem

It gives this error if moved to 1.5.6

Comment: do a clean maven build, refer this guide for more info https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: Yet it shows the same error even after clean build.
The jar which it is pointing out as missing is listed in the maven dependencies.

Comment: Correction:::: Not as missing but "cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP"

Comment: The logback invalid issue got resolved with using updated Maven version instead of the embeded one. But still not able to understand why SPring 1.3.3 server stopped after main execution.

Comment: I have the same error in Spring boot version 1.5.2 https://stackoverflow.com/q/45919310/2028440, no idea why.

Comment: Since it is simple app with one class, why don't you create new spring boot app with just spring boot starter dependency and run