# Spring boot 1.5.2 - web application stops after loading logo?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, runtime-error, liquibase

I have a very weird problem with Spring Boot, I don't know why the web application which using Spring Boot cannot start and it has no output error even when I run it directly on the terminal.

```
java -jar /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/rasdaman.war
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

. ____ _ __ _ _
/\ / ' __ _ () __ __ _ \ \ \ 
( ( )__ | '_ | '| | ' / ` | \ \ \ 
\/ )| |)| | | | | || (| | ) ) ) )
' || .__|| ||| |_, | / / / /
=========||==============|/=////
:: Spring Boot :: (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

[rasdaman@osboxes rasdaman]$ echo $?
1
```

Here is the application class https://pastebin.com/rinWbp9z, this web application uses Liquibase to populate database schema and Spring boot `version 1.5.2`. Can you please share some hint to debug?

Comment: Does it really stop or is it just the logging that stops... log4j isn't supported anymore in Spring Boot 1.5 and up (log4j2 is).

Comment: Your logging system is not initialized properly, that's why you don't see anything past the logo. Are you sure your app isn't up? Try to remove any customization you've made to logging configuration for a start.

Comment: I can use log4j with a property file and this web application can run on my development system without error (i.e: it will continue to run until it shows the log about Spring Boot application started after ... seconds).

But I don't understand why this application if copied to a new Virtual Machine, it will stop right after the logo (?). I tried to set log level in log4j property file to DEBUG and it does not show anything also. I think Spring Boot created a fat jar so all dependencies are in this (war/jar) file already.

Comment: Your code needs to be here, not on some other site, and you need to reduce it to the point where it demonstrates the problem [mcve]. Please read [ask]

Comment: @EngineerDollery I wish I could narrow the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776035/spring-boot-server-stops-after-main-method-execution, looks like same problem as yours

Comment: yes, I did not know this problem happened before with version 1.3.3

Answer (score 9):

So, the problem is, I'm using log4.properties out of war file. Then, when I starts this war, It shows **very nice** information like this:

```
java -jar target/petascope_main/rasdaman.war
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

Aug 28, 2017 6:00:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Aug 28, 2017 6:00:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
Aug 28, 2017 6:00:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Aug 28, 2017 6:00:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Tomcat
```

Then, I added a log4j.properties file in src/main/resources with this content:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n
```

After that, I can see the detail log from Spring which make Tomcat stop:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field abstractHandler in org.rasdaman.ApplicationMain required a single bean, but 7 were found:
    - KVPRasqlServiceHandler: defined in URL [jar:file:/home/rasdaman/build/applications/petascope/target/petascope_main/rasdaman.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/petascope/controller/handler/service/KVPRasqlServiceHandler.class]
    - KVPWCPSServiceHandler: defined in URL [jar:file:/home/rasdaman/build/applications/petascope/target/petascope_main/rasdaman.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/petascope/controller/handler/service/KVPWCPSServiceHandler.class]
    - SOAPWCSServiceHandler: defined in URL [jar:file:/home/rasdaman/build/applications/petascope/target/petascope_main/rasdaman.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/petascope/controller/handler/service/SOAPWCSServiceHandler.class]
    - KVPWCSTServiceHandler: defined in URL [jar:file:/home/rasdaman/build/applications/petascope/target/petascope_main/rasdaman.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/petascope/controller/handler/service/KVPWCSTServiceHandler.class]
    - XMLWCSServiceHandler: defined in URL [jar:file:/home/rasdaman/build/applications/petascope/target/petascope_main/rasdaman.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/petascope/controller/handler/service/XMLWCSServiceHandler.class]
    - KVPWCSServiceHandler: defined in URL [jar:file:/home/rasdaman/build/applications/petascope/target/petascope_main/rasdaman.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/petascope/controller/handler/service/KVPWCSServiceHandler.class]
    - KVPWMSServiceHandler: defined in URL [jar:file:/home/rasdaman/build/applications/petascope/target/petascope_main/rasdaman.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/petascope/controller/handler/service/KVPWMSServiceHandler.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Well, I must say, *it is really impressive about how error could be hidden.*

Comment: "Well, I must say, it is really impressive about how error could be hidden." - Well written.. same here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your configuration for logback is correct !

When you configure your logback-spring.xml after that the logs does not appear on the console. 
Instead, you need to go to the LOG_HOME location which you configured in your logback-spring.xml file.

All the logs will be in file and not on console.

Please let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to solve this problem, it was long time ago and I don't recall it anymore.