# Spring Boot application suddenly stops after outputing logo and version on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

When I execute Run As -> Java application my Spring Boot application class on Eclipse, I get Spring Boot logo and version in logs but it halts and stops after few seconds:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

Spring version: 1.5.9.RELEASE
```

There are no errors in console.

Tried but didn't help:

- Project -> Clean, project refresh on Eclipse
- `gradle clean`, `build`, `eclipse` from command line
- Deleted and imported project from git again
- Restart Eclipse

Tried solutions from related SO threads:

- [Spring boot 1.5.2 - web application stops after loading logo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919310/spring-boot-1-5-2-web-application-stops-after-loading-logo)
- [spring boot server stops after main method execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776035/spring-boot-server-stops-after-main-method-execution?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Also:

- If I run tests from Eclipse, they pass successfully.
- Other Spring Boot apps run well on Eclipse.
- When I try to run application from command line with `gradle bootRun`, it runs smoothly.

Why does it happen? How to solve it?

Comment: please share any errors?

Comment: There are no errors in console.

Comment: check main class configured following annotations,  @SpringBootApplication,@EnableAutoConfiguration

Comment: Yes, they are. As I mentioned, it works well from cmd.

Comment: oh okey. but without error, without knowing rootcause we cant find solution

Comment: if you set the [log level to DEBUG](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-console-output), can you spot anything funny?

Comment: No, as I mentioned before - it runs well from cmd.

Comment: Well if you set the root logger to DEBUG level, you should see waaaaay a lot more stuff. What you pasted there is just the banner so I'd try to figure out why there's nothing else in there. Perhaps you don't have any console appender and everything is written to a file?

Comment: If I set 'debug: true' in application.yml, I see extended logs when I run from cmd but not from Eclipse.

Comment: There is no other property for logging.

Comment: How did you configure your app's logging? Can you please share its configuration?

Comment: Found the problem - deleted logback.xml from src/main/resources and logback-test.xml from src/test/resources and it worked - strange why.

Comment: Probably because there were only files appenders defined, thus nothing was being directed to the console.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Deleted `logback.xml` from `src/main/resources` and `logback-test.xml` from `src/test/resources` and it worked.

Comment: I wouldn't completely delete the logging configuration since you'll need it when deploying in production (if it's not just a _for fun_ app). Probably there were only file appenders in the `logback.xml`, or the console appender was not used, and so everything was logged into a file. Try looking in the xml and see where the output was directed, and inspect the log file for errors. Alternatively, define and use some console appenders to see the logs in you IDE (maybe use profile based log configs for easy maintenance).

Comment: There was no specific direction: <configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="ERROR" />
</configuration>

Comment: Previously logs were written to 2 files on Ubuntu: /tmp/spring.log and log/current. Now it writes only to {springBootAppLocation}/log/current so it is what I expect.

Comment: OK, I'll take your word for it since it's difficult to guess what was going on there without seeing the whole picture :-). However if you need to change the logging config, you can start from the [boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) or any other tutorial of choice.

Answer (score 2):

In my case It was fixed when added the spring boot web dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Or, if you are using Gradle : `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'`

Answer (score 1):

If the answers above are not satisfactory the issue in my case was that I was including dependency with its own slf4j setup, that got in clash with Spring Boot's one (old vs. new).

The problem was that the dependency was accidentally built as fat-jar.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot is still working, just there is no output in the console after logo. Server will startup if there are no other issues.

In my case Spring Boot console stopped logging after i renamed application.properties into core.properties (that file is referred in logback.xml)

```
<define name="internalFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.property.ResourceExistsPropertyDefiner">
    <resource>application.properties</resource>
</define>
```

After updating the resource tag, console output was back.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the reason was that I was using an alpha release of sl4j. When i replaced it with an older one I was able to start the spring boot application.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue from upgrading the `slf4j-api` dependency from `1.X` to `2.0.6`.  We were able to resolve by adding `slf4j-simple:2.0.6` dependency as well. The slf4j patch notes for version `2.0` go over this topic [here](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#changesInVersion200). Spring hanging on the logo appears to be an additional side effect.

| slf4j-api version | slf4j-simple version | Result | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.0.x | 2.0.x | OK | Same version for slf4j-api and provider |
| 1.7.x | 2.0.x | no bindings can be found warning message | 2.0.x providers do not act as 1.7.x/1.6.x compatible bindings |
| 2.0.x | 1.7.x | no providers can be found warning message | slf4j-api 2.0.x will no longer search for StaticLoggerBinding |

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my spring boot application was out of `application.properties`, so I just added it back and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when running a natively compiled binary in SpringBoot 3.2.2. When building with `./gradlew nativeBuild` and executing `build/native/nativeCompile/appname`.

I am using an external build script that I get from Nexus as a dependency and apply in my `build.gradle`. My problem was that I applied the `org.graalvm.buildtools.native` that build script and the SpringBoot plugin `org.springframework.boot` in `build.gradle`. This will cause classloader issue when the 2 plugins do not use the same classloader.

I solved it by applying both plugins in `build.gradle`.

I was helped by this comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34758#issuecomment-1483178673